Possible causes for css sticky positioning in a <thead> to not work
I've created a custom element that mimics c#’s datagridview. I was able to make the <thead> stick at the top like dot net’s listview or datagridview header until just recently I noticed it doesn’t work anymore.
Everything in this custom element are programmatically generated including the CSS rules. Here’s the code to generate the CSS rules:
class ListView extends HTMLElement {
    static #lvwId = null;
    static #lvwCss;
    static #initId() {
        if (ListView.#lvwId == null) {
            ListView.#lvwId = '-lvw-' + Array.from(Date.now().toString()).map(b => ('00' + b.toString(16)).slice(-2)).join('');
            ListView.#lvwCss = ListView.#lvwId + '-css';
        }
    }
    connectedCallback() {
        ListView.#initId();
        let style = document.getElementById(ListView.#lvwId);
        if (style == null) {
            ListView.#style = style = document.createElement('style');
            style.type = 'text/css';
            style.id = ListView.#lvwId;
            const fn = (...b) => {
                if (b.length == 1) {
                    let c = b[0];
                    let d = '.' + ListView.#lvwCss;
                    if (c[0] == '-')
                        c = c.substr(1);
                    else
                        d += ' ';
                    d += c;
                    ListView.#style.appendChild(document.createTextNode(d));
                }
                else {
                    let c = '';
                    for (let d of b[0]) {
                        if (c != '') c += ',';
                        c += '.' + ListView.#lvwCss + ' ' + d;
                    }
                    ListView.#style.appendChild(document.createTextNode(c + ' ' + b[1]));
                }
            };
            fn('{position:relative;background-color:white;outline:none;display:block;overflow:auto;}');
            fn('*{user-select:none;box-sizing:border-box;position:relative;padding:0px;margin:0px;background-color:transparent;color:inherit}');
            fn('{--gridcolor:lightgray;--xmargins:5px;--itembackcolor:white;--itemforecolor:black;--headerbackcolor:gray;--headerforecolor:black;--headerhoverback:forestgreen;--headerhoverfore:black;--headerpadding:4px;--itempadding:4px;}');
            fn('table{border-collapse:collapse;z-index:0;left:0px;top:0px;background:white;table-layout:fixed;display:block}');
            fn('thead{position:sticky;top:0px;z-index:3}');
            fn('thead>tr{position:sticky}');
            fn(['th', 'td'], '{text-align:left;vertical-align:top;}');
            fn('th{position:sticky;top:-1px;background-color:var(--headerbackcolor);color:var(--headerforecolor);border-right:1px solid var(--gridcolor);transition:background-color .5s}');
            fn('-:not([headeronly]) th{cursor:pointer;}');
            fn('-:not([headeronly]) th:hover{background-color:var(--headerhoverback);color:var(--headerhoverfore)}');
            fn(['th>div', 'td>div'], '{height:100%;display:flex;flex-direction:row;justify-content:flex-start;align-content:flex-start;align-items:flex-start}');
            fn('th>div{margin-left:var(--xmargins);padding: var(--headerpadding) var(--xmargins) var(--headerpadding) 0px;}');
            fn('th>div>p{width:100%}');
            fn('td{background:var(--itembackcolor);color:var(--itemforecolor);}')
            fn('th::after{content:"";width:var(--xmargins);position:absolute;right:0px;top:0px;height:100%;cursor:ew-resize}')
            fn('th:not(:first-child)::before{content:"";width:var(--xmargins);position:absolute;left:0px;top:0px;height:100%;cursor:ew-resize}')
            fn('td>div{padding:var(--xmargins) var(--itempadding);width:100%;}');
            fn('td>div>p>img{float:left;margin-right:5px}');
            fn('td>input{height:100%;width:100%;outline:0px solid transparent;border:none;padding:1px;background:white;color:black;}');
            fn('td{color:black}');
            fn('tr[selected]{background:#018;color:white}');
            fn('tr[selected]>td:not([selected]){background:transparent;color:white}');
            fn('tr[selected]>td[selected]{background:rgba(255,255,255,.2);}');
            fn('tbody>tr:nth-child(even){--bg-color:rgba(0,0,0,.05)}');
            fn('tbody>tr:nth-child(even) td{background-color:var(--bg-color);}');
            fn('.sticky-hdr{position:sticky;overflow:hidden;z-index:1;top:0px;width:100%}');
            fn('tbody>tr{border-bottom:1px solid var(--gridcolor);color:black}');
            fn('.splits{border-top:1px solid var(--gridcolor)}');
            fn('tbody>tr>td p{outline:none;width:100%;}');
            fn('tbody td{border-right:1px solid var(--gridcolor)}');
            fn('-[nogrid] tbody * {border-color:transparent}');
            fn('-[nogrid] tbody>tr:nth-child(even)>td{border-color:var(--bg-color)}');
            fn('-[nowrap] p{white-space:nowrap;text-overflow:ellipsis;overflow:hidden}');
            fn('-[checkboxes] td>div>div[checkbox]{float:left;border:1px solid gray;margin-right:5px;width:16px;height:16px;background:white}')
            fn("-[checkboxes] td>div>div[checkbox=\"checked\"]::after{content: url(\"data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' x='0' y='0' viewbow='0 0 16 16'%3E%3Cpath fill='black' d='M4,9l0,-3l3,3l5,-5,l0,3l-5,5Z' /%3E%3C/svg%3E\");width:16px;height:16px;position:absolute;left:-1.5px;top:-1px}");
            document.body.insertAdjacentElement('beforebegin', style);
        }
        this.tabIndex = $(this).index();
        $(this).addClass(ListView.#lvwCss);
        this.#headerPlaceholder = document.createElement('div');
        this.#headerPlaceholder.setAttribute('style', 'width:100%;height:32px;overflow:none;position:sticky;left:0px;top:0px;background:gray');
        this.#headerPlaceholder.innerHTML = '&nbsp;';
        this.append(this.#headerPlaceholder);
        this.#table = document.createElement('table');
        this.#table.style.top = '0px';
        this.#thead = document.createElement('thead');
        this.#table.appendChild(this.#thead);
        this.#tbody = document.createElement('tbody');
        this.#table.appendChild(this.#tbody);
        this.#header = document.createElement('tr');
        this.#table.firstChild.insertAdjacentElement('afterbegin', this.#header);
        $(this).append(this.#table);

        this.#handleEvents();
        this.#handleHeaderEvents();

        const observer = new ResizeObserver(entries => {
            const ofh = this.#thead.offsetHeight - 1;
            this.#headerPlaceholder.style.height = ofh + 'px';
            this.#table.style.top = (-ofh) + 'px';
        });
        observer.observe(this.#thead);
    }
}

Inside the connectedCallback function is the creation of this.#headerPlaceholder:
        this.#headerPlaceholder = document.createElement('div');
        this.#headerPlaceholder.setAttribute('style', 'width:100%;height:32px;overflow:none;position:sticky;left:0px;top:0px;background:gray');
        this.#headerPlaceholder.innerHTML = '&nbsp;';

And as you can see, this element is sticky and it do sticks. But it’s the <thead> that sticky positioning don’t work. Again, it was working and I don’t know why it just suddenly stopped working.
I have searched a lot to find the cause of this but I’ve got no clue. I followed the suggested solutions and accepted solutions I’ve found in stackoverflow like combining sticky position with css top rule but still it doesn’t work. I've tried using position fixed but it created another problem of column sizes e.g. <th> element not following the width value and header column widths and td widths not the same. I’ve checked if outside rules are affecting but nothing I’ve found so far. I have also extended the sticky position to all <tr>s and <th>s but to no avail.
A non-jquery solution is preferrable although you might observe that there are some jquery calls in the snippet I have posted. I am trying my custom element to have less to zero dependencies but as of now it uses jquery in some parts.
Update
I can’t directly paste the generated CSS and mark-up here but I think links will do:
Generated CSS: https://pastebin.com/embed_js/9tVx409n
Generated mark-up: https://pastebin.com/embed_js/6EmpvY6Q
Edit: adding an SO snippet:


<div class="flex fdcol jcsb cx100 cy100">
  <div class="cx100 cy100">
    <ek-listview class="cx100 -lvw-01070108000005050008030200-css" id="lvw" nowrap="" style="border: 1px solid rgb(170, 170, 170); width: 1094px; height: 265.672px;" tabindex="0">
      <table style="top: 0px; width: 890px;">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th style="width: 250px;">
              <div>
                <p style="text-align: left;">Name</p>
              </div>
            </th>
            <th style="width: 100px;">
              <div>
                <p style="text-align: left;">Bio Name</p>
              </div>
            </th>
            <th style="width: 100px;">
              <div>
                <p style="text-align: left;">Date Hired</p>
              </div>
            </th>
            <th style="width: 120px;">
              <div>
                <p style="text-align: left;">Service Length</p>
              </div>
            </th>
            <th style="width: 120px;">
              <div>
                <p style="text-align: left;">Position</p>
              </div>
            </th>
            <th style="width: 90px;">
              <div>
                <p style="text-align: right;">Salary</p>
              </div>
            </th>
            <th style="width: 110px;">
              <div>
                <p style="text-align: right;">Payments</p>
              </div>
            </th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <div>
                <p><span>Employee 1</span></p>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>
                <p><span></span></p>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>
                <p><span>Aug 1, 2019</span></p>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>
                <p><span>4 years, 10 months &amp; 9 days</span></p>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>
                <p><span>Sales Executive</span></p>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>
                <p style="text-align: right;"><span>9,000.00</span></p>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>
                <p style="text-align: right;"><span></span></p>
              </div>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <div>
                <p><span>Employee 2</span></p>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>
                <p><span></span></p>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>
                <p><span>May 3, 2023</span></p>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>
                <p><span>1 year, 1 month &amp; 7 days</span></p>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>
                <p><span>Installer</span></p>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>
                <p style="text-align: right;"><span>9,100.00</span></p>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>
                <p style="text-align: right;"><span></span></p>
              </div>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <div>
                <p><span>Employee 4</span></p>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>
                <p><span></span></p>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>
                <p><span>Dec 7, 2021</span></p>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>
                <p><span>2 years, 6 months &amp; 3 days</span></p>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>
                <p><span>Installer</span></p>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>
                <p style="text-align: right;"><span>10,400.00</span></p>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>
                <p style="text-align: right;"><span></span></p>
              </div>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <div>
                <p><span>Employee 5</span></p>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>
                <p><span></span></p>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>
                <p><span>May 1, 2023</span></p>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>
                <p><span>1 year, 1 month &amp; 8 days</span></p>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>
                <p><span>Installer</span></p>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>
                <p style="text-align: right;"><span>9,999.00</span></p>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>
                <p style="text-align: right;"><span></span></p>
              </div>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <div>
                <p><span>Employee 6</span></p>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>
                <p><span></span></p>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>
                <p><span>Apr 4, 2024</span></p>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>
                <p><span>0 year, 2 months &amp; 6 days</span></p>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>
                <p><span>Office Admin</span></p>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>
                <p style="text-align: right;"><span>9,750.00</span></p>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>
                <p style="text-align: right;"><span></span></p>
              </div>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <div>
                <p><span>Employee 7</span></p>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>
                <p><span></span></p>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>
                <p><span>Mar 1, 2024</span></p>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>
                <p><span>0 year, 3 months &amp; 9 days</span></p>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>
                <p><span>Installer</span></p>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>
                <p style="text-align: right;"><span>10,444.00</span></p>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>
                <p style="text-align: right;"><span></span></p>
              </div>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <div>
                <p><span>Employee 8</span></p>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>
                <p><span></span></p>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>
                <p><span>Apr 3, 2024</span></p>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>
                <p><span>0 year, 2 months &amp; 6 days</span></p>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>
                <p><span>Installer</span></p>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>
                <p style="text-align: right;"><span>9,750.00</span></p>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>
                <p style="text-align: right;"><span></span></p>
              </div>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <div>
                <p><span>Employee 9</span></p>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>
                <p><span></span></p>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>
                <p><span>Sep 11, 2023</span></p>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>
                <p><span>0 year, 8 months &amp; 29 days</span></p>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>
                <p><span>Area Supervisor</span></p>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>
                <p style="text-align: right;"><span>9,750.00</span></p>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>
                <p style="text-align: right;"><span></span></p>
              </div>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <div>
                <p><span>Employee 10</span></p>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>
                <p><span></span></p>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>
                <p><span>Feb 1, 2024</span></p>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>
                <p><span>0 year, 4 months &amp; 9 days</span></p>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>
                <p><span>IT Programmer</span></p>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>
                <p style="text-align: right;"><span>12,000.00</span></p>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>
                <p style="text-align: right;"><span></span></p>
              </div>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <div>
                <p><span>Employee 11</span></p>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>
                <p><span></span></p>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>
                <p><span>Feb 26, 2024</span></p>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>
                <p><span>0 year, 3 months &amp; 13 days</span></p>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>
                <p><span>Office Admin</span></p>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>
                <p style="text-align: right;"><span>9,750.00</span></p>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>
                <p style="text-align: right;"><span></span></p>
              </div>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </ek-listview>
  </div>
</div>
<style type="text/css" id="-lvw-01070107090900090401010003">
  .-lvw-01070107090900090401010003-css {
    position: relative;
    background-color: white;
    outline: none;
    display: block;
    overflow: auto;
  }
  
  .-lvw-01070107090900090401010003-css * {
    user-select: none;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    background-color: transparent;
    color: inherit
  }
  
  .-lvw-01070107090900090401010003-css {
    --gridcolor: lightgray;
    --xmargins: 5px;
    --itembackcolor: white;
    --itemforecolor: black;
    --headerbackcolor: gray;
    --headerforecolor: black;
    --headerhoverback: forestgreen;
    --headerhoverfore: black;
    --headerpadding: 4px;
    --itempadding: 4px;
  }
  
  .-lvw-01070107090900090401010003-css table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    z-index: 0;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    background: white;
    table-layout: fixed;
    display: block
  }
  
  .-lvw-01070107090900090401010003-css thead {
    position: sticky;
    z-index: 11;
    top: 0px
  }
  
  .-lvw-01070107090900090401010003-css th,
  .-lvw-01070107090900090401010003-css td {
    text-align: left;
    vertical-align: top;
  }
  
  .-lvw-01070107090900090401010003-css th {
    position: sticky;
    top: 0px;
    background-color: var(--headerbackcolor);
    color: var(--headerforecolor);
    border-right: 1px solid var(--gridcolor);
    transition: background-color .5s
  }
  
  .-lvw-01070107090900090401010003-css:not([headeronly]) th {
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  
  .-lvw-01070107090900090401010003-css:not([headeronly]) th:hover {
    background-color: var(--headerhoverback);
    color: var(--headerhoverfore)
  }
  
  .-lvw-01070107090900090401010003-css th>div,
  .-lvw-01070107090900090401010003-css td>div {
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-content: flex-start;
    align-items: flex-start
  }
  
  .-lvw-01070107090900090401010003-css th>div {
    margin-left: var(--xmargins);
    padding: var(--headerpadding) var(--xmargins) var(--headerpadding) 0px;
  }
  
  .-lvw-01070107090900090401010003-css th>div>p {
    width: 100%
  }
  
  .-lvw-01070107090900090401010003-css td {
    background: var(--itembackcolor);
    color: var(--itemforecolor);
  }
  
  .-lvw-01070107090900090401010003-css th::after {
    content: "";
    width: var(--xmargins);
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    height: 100%;
    cursor: ew-resize
  }
  
  .-lvw-01070107090900090401010003-css th:not(:first-child)::before {
    content: "";
    width: var(--xmargins);
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    height: 100%;
    cursor: ew-resize
  }
  
  .-lvw-01070107090900090401010003-css td>div {
    padding: var(--xmargins) var(--itempadding);
    width: 100%;
  }
  
  .-lvw-01070107090900090401010003-css td>div>p>img {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 5px
  }
  
  .-lvw-01070107090900090401010003-css td>input {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    outline: 0px solid transparent;
    border: none;
    padding: 1px;
    background: white;
    color: black;
  }
  
  .-lvw-01070107090900090401010003-css td {
    color: black
  }
  
  .-lvw-01070107090900090401010003-css tr[selected] {
    background: #018;
    color: white
  }
  
  .-lvw-01070107090900090401010003-css tr[selected]>td:not([selected]) {
    background: transparent;
    color: white
  }
  
  .-lvw-01070107090900090401010003-css tr[selected]>td[selected] {
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .2);
  }
  
  .-lvw-01070107090900090401010003-css tbody>tr:nth-child(even) {
    --bg-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .05)
  }
  
  .-lvw-01070107090900090401010003-css tbody>tr:nth-child(even) td {
    background-color: var(--bg-color);
  }
  
  .-lvw-01070107090900090401010003-css tbody>tr {
    border-bottom: 1px solid var(--gridcolor);
    color: black
  }
  
  .-lvw-01070107090900090401010003-css .splits {
    border-top: 1px solid var(--gridcolor)
  }
  
  .-lvw-01070107090900090401010003-css tbody>tr>td p {
    outline: none;
    width: 100%;
  }
  
  .-lvw-01070107090900090401010003-css tbody td {
    border-right: 1px solid var(--gridcolor)
  }
  
  .-lvw-01070107090900090401010003-css[nogrid] tbody * {
    border-color: transparent
  }
  
  .-lvw-01070107090900090401010003-css[nogrid] tbody>tr:nth-child(even)>td {
    border-color: var(--bg-color)
  }
  
  .-lvw-01070107090900090401010003-css[nowrap] p {
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden
  }
  
  .-lvw-01070107090900090401010003-css[checkboxes] td>div>div[checkbox] {
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    margin-right: 5px;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    background: white
  }
  
  .-lvw-01070107090900090401010003-css[checkboxes] td>div>div[checkbox="checked"]::after {
    content: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns=\'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\' x=\'0\' y=\'0\' viewbow=\'0 0 16 16\'%3E%3Cpath fill=\'black\' d=\'M4,9l0,-3l3,3l5,-5,l0,3l-5,5Z\' /%3E%3C/svg%3E");
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    position: absolute;
    left: -1.5px;
    top: -1px
  }
</style>




There's no simple test code to look at here.

Can you show us the relevant generated CSS and related HTML.

Shall I append it to my post as update?

Edit your question to include it.

I am trying to post the generated CSS and mark-up but it is still being declined saying it's a code unformatted property. I have already converted all < to < and > to > but they are still rejected. I put them inside the  tag but still not accepted. Oh...I desperately need a help on this one...

Are you using your browser devtools inspect facility to get exactly what html and css being created?

Yes, I am. Actually, as I've said, my widget was working as I have been using it in my c# app with CEF. Only last night that I've noticed it was not working any more. And it was working in browser too until I found out last night that it no longer works. I have here the generated CSS and mark-up only that I don't know how to put in my question as it is being declined by the editor.

You should be able to copy it and paste it as code using the {}

That's what I did but for some reason it was not accepted. The editor just said I have to format it properly. Then I tried the  tags but it was rejected too.

That’s weird. Perhaps you’d better post a url where we can pick up the code.

I already did. Please see my post.

I can't see why you weren't allowed to add a snippet. I have created one using the links you have given, but I note that it appears not to be the final generated code as there seem to be some non-standard tags in there.

Look at the sticky setting. There is one on thead but it's been given an ancestor's class which isn't correct - it seems to correspond (?) to the id that is on the style element. Weird - are you looking carefully using your browser devtools inspect facility to see exactly what is going on? It looks obvious.

I think the only thing that the ancestor's class setting you are talking about is the display which is set to block the overrides the default display setting of a thead which is table-header-group. I've just set the that setting in the display rule of the thead but still it doesn't stick.

Yes, I just saw that although it shouldn't be that way because the ID is only created once and that id is the id given to the style element. All instances of the ek-listview elements will be using one single style rule. I don't know why the numbers in class name of ek-listview from what I have posted differs to the numbers in the ID given to the style element. But I can confirm it here in my PC that they are all the same. But being the same does not solve the problem.

Being all the same does solve the problem for me using otherwise exactly the code you have provided. If they are all the same for you please update the code in the question with what you actually have rather than the code you gave us, and check that the snippet shows the problem of non-stickiness.

Since the problem seems to be the dynamic class name creation and not the CSS itself you should edit your question to focus on the JavaScript part. Besides, please add the JS tag to your post


Ditch the super-specific time based CSS-selectors and use a generic selector for your style. If multiple instances share the same styles - just use a global stylesheet, ditch the ID generation as well - no need to append them to the DOM each time the component is injected. 2. reduce your component code to the bare minimum - the stylesheet generation currently bloats you code unnecessarily. Ideally share a So snippet explaining how the component works (3 table rows are enough). 3. Revise your answer and add a web-component tag to it. Nothing wrong with the CSS - apart from the selectors.


@herrstrietzel The code I posted is part of larger code of a custom HTMLElement I am writing. The element is some kind of a listview of datagridview and I want it to have its own default styles hence the dynamic creation of the css. Among its features is the ability to resize column via mouse, in place editing of cells like an excel worksheet. Except from adding the element in the html page, everything is controlled by script: adding of headers, rows and the creation of CSS. So writing a separate css I think is not an option. They are all in a single unit.

I wrote a simple markup and minimal CSS to see something and I've got the goal of keeping the thead stick. The mark-up was the same with what I posted: a table inside a div. The div is the scroll bars server. What I noticed is that when I set both the width and the height of the div to a percentage, the thead don't stick. One of them had to have a value other than percentage.

@herrstrietzel Sorry for the confusion. But what I meant was I wrote something minimal for sampling. Not the one which is the subject of this thread.

The class of the ek-listview ancestor does not match all the classes of the ancestors in the CSS.
The CSS has .-lvw-01070107090900090401010003-css
The ek-listview has class -lvw-01070108000005050008030200-css
Changing the class (by hand) in the snippet gives formatting of the table, with the thead having position sticky.


<div class="flex fdcol jcsb cx100 cy100">
  <div class="cx100 cy100">
    <ek-listview class="cx100 -lvw-01070107090900090401010003-css" id="lvw" nowrap="" style="border: 1px solid rgb(170, 170, 170); width: 1094px; height: 265.672px;" tabindex="0">
      <table style="top: 0px; width: 890px;">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th style="width: 250px;">
              <div>
                <p style="text-align: left;">Name</p>
              </div>
            </th>
            <th style="width: 100px;">
              <div>
                <p style="text-align: left;">Bio Name</p>
              </div>
            </th>
            <th style="width: 100px;">
              <div>
                <p style="text-align: left;">Date Hired</p>
              </div>
            </th>
            <th style="width: 120px;">
              <div>
                <p style="text-align: left;">Service Length</p>
              </div>
            </th>
            <th style="width: 120px;">
              <div>
                <p style="text-align: left;">Position</p>
              </div>
            </th>
            <th style="width: 90px;">
              <div>
                <p style="text-align: right;">Salary</p>
              </div>
            </th>
            <th style="width: 110px;">
              <div>
                <p style="text-align: right;">Payments</p>
              </div>
            </th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <div>
                <p><span>Employee 1</span></p>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>
                <p><span></span></p>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>
                <p><span>Aug 1, 2019</span></p>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>
                <p><span>4 years, 10 months &amp; 9 days</span></p>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>
                <p><span>Sales Executive</span></p>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>
                <p style="text-align: right;"><span>9,000.00</span></p>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>
                <p style="text-align: right;"><span></span></p>
              </div>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <div>
                <p><span>Employee 2</span></p>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>
                <p><span></span></p>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>
                <p><span>May 3, 2023</span></p>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>
                <p><span>1 year, 1 month &amp; 7 days</span></p>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>
                <p><span>Installer</span></p>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>
                <p style="text-align: right;"><span>9,100.00</span></p>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>
                <p style="text-align: right;"><span></span></p>
              </div>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <div>
                <p><span>Employee 4</span></p>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>
                <p><span></span></p>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>
                <p><span>Dec 7, 2021</span></p>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>
                <p><span>2 years, 6 months &amp; 3 days</span></p>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>
                <p><span>Installer</span></p>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>
                <p style="text-align: right;"><span>10,400.00</span></p>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>
                <p style="text-align: right;"><span></span></p>
              </div>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <div>
                <p><span>Employee 5</span></p>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>
                <p><span></span></p>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>
                <p><span>May 1, 2023</span></p>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>
                <p><span>1 year, 1 month &amp; 8 days</span></p>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>
                <p><span>Installer</span></p>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>
                <p style="text-align: right;"><span>9,999.00</span></p>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>
                <p style="text-align: right;"><span></span></p>
              </div>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <div>
                <p><span>Employee 6</span></p>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>
                <p><span></span></p>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>
                <p><span>Apr 4, 2024</span></p>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>
                <p><span>0 year, 2 months &amp; 6 days</span></p>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>
                <p><span>Office Admin</span></p>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>
                <p style="text-align: right;"><span>9,750.00</span></p>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>
                <p style="text-align: right;"><span></span></p>
              </div>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <div>
                <p><span>Employee 7</span></p>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>
                <p><span></span></p>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>
                <p><span>Mar 1, 2024</span></p>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>
                <p><span>0 year, 3 months &amp; 9 days</span></p>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>
                <p><span>Installer</span></p>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>
                <p style="text-align: right;"><span>10,444.00</span></p>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>
                <p style="text-align: right;"><span></span></p>
              </div>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <div>
                <p><span>Employee 8</span></p>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>
                <p><span></span></p>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>
                <p><span>Apr 3, 2024</span></p>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>
                <p><span>0 year, 2 months &amp; 6 days</span></p>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>
                <p><span>Installer</span></p>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>
                <p style="text-align: right;"><span>9,750.00</span></p>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>
                <p style="text-align: right;"><span></span></p>
              </div>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <div>
                <p><span>Employee 9</span></p>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>
                <p><span></span></p>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>
                <p><span>Sep 11, 2023</span></p>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>
                <p><span>0 year, 8 months &amp; 29 days</span></p>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>
                <p><span>Area Supervisor</span></p>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>
                <p style="text-align: right;"><span>9,750.00</span></p>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>
                <p style="text-align: right;"><span></span></p>
              </div>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <div>
                <p><span>Employee 10</span></p>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>
                <p><span></span></p>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>
                <p><span>Feb 1, 2024</span></p>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>
                <p><span>0 year, 4 months &amp; 9 days</span></p>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>
                <p><span>IT Programmer</span></p>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>
                <p style="text-align: right;"><span>12,000.00</span></p>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>
                <p style="text-align: right;"><span></span></p>
              </div>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <div>
                <p><span>Employee 11</span></p>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>
                <p><span></span></p>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>
                <p><span>Feb 26, 2024</span></p>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>
                <p><span>0 year, 3 months &amp; 13 days</span></p>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>
                <p><span>Office Admin</span></p>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>
                <p style="text-align: right;"><span>9,750.00</span></p>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>
                <p style="text-align: right;"><span></span></p>
              </div>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </ek-listview>
  </div>
</div>
<style type="text/css" id="-lvw-01070107090900090401010003">
  .-lvw-01070107090900090401010003-css {
    position: relative;
    background-color: pink;
    outline: none;
    display: block;
    overflow: auto;
  }
  
  .-lvw-01070107090900090401010003-css * {
    user-select: none;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    background-color: transparent;
    color: inherit
  }
  
  .-lvw-01070107090900090401010003-css {
    --gridcolor: lightgray;
    --xmargins: 5px;
    --itembackcolor: white;
    --itemforecolor: black;
    --headerbackcolor: gray;
    --headerforecolor: black;
    --headerhoverback: forestgreen;
    --headerhoverfore: black;
    --headerpadding: 4px;
    --itempadding: 4px;
  }
  
  .-lvw-01070107090900090401010003-css table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    z-index: 0;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    background: white;
    table-layout: fixed;
    display: block
  }
  
  .-lvw-01070107090900090401010003-css thead {
    position: sticky;
    z-index: 11;
    top: 0px
  }
  
  .-lvw-01070107090900090401010003-css th,
  .-lvw-01070107090900090401010003-css td {
    text-align: left;
    vertical-align: top;
  }
  
  .-lvw-01070107090900090401010003-css th {
    position: sticky;
    top: 0px;
    background-color: var(--headerbackcolor);
    color: var(--headerforecolor);
    border-right: 1px solid var(--gridcolor);
    transition: background-color .5s
  }
  
  .-lvw-01070107090900090401010003-css:not([headeronly]) th {
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  
  .-lvw-01070107090900090401010003-css:not([headeronly]) th:hover {
    background-color: var(--headerhoverback);
    color: var(--headerhoverfore)
  }
  
  .-lvw-01070107090900090401010003-css th>div,
  .-lvw-01070107090900090401010003-css td>div {
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-content: flex-start;
    align-items: flex-start
  }
  
  .-lvw-01070107090900090401010003-css th>div {
    margin-left: var(--xmargins);
    padding: var(--headerpadding) var(--xmargins) var(--headerpadding) 0px;
  }
  
  .-lvw-01070107090900090401010003-css th>div>p {
    width: 100%
  }
  
  .-lvw-01070107090900090401010003-css td {
    background: var(--itembackcolor);
    color: var(--itemforecolor);
  }
  
  .-lvw-01070107090900090401010003-css th::after {
    content: "";
    width: var(--xmargins);
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    height: 100%;
    cursor: ew-resize
  }
  
  .-lvw-01070107090900090401010003-css th:not(:first-child)::before {
    content: "";
    width: var(--xmargins);
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    height: 100%;
    cursor: ew-resize
  }
  
  .-lvw-01070107090900090401010003-css td>div {
    padding: var(--xmargins) var(--itempadding);
    width: 100%;
  }
  
  .-lvw-01070107090900090401010003-css td>div>p>img {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 5px
  }
  
  .-lvw-01070107090900090401010003-css td>input {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    outline: 0px solid transparent;
    border: none;
    padding: 1px;
    background: white;
    color: black;
  }
  
  .-lvw-01070107090900090401010003-css td {
    color: black
  }
  
  .-lvw-01070107090900090401010003-css tr[selected] {
    background: #018;
    color: white
  }
  
  .-lvw-01070107090900090401010003-css tr[selected]>td:not([selected]) {
    background: transparent;
    color: white
  }
  
  .-lvw-01070107090900090401010003-css tr[selected]>td[selected] {
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .2);
  }
  
  .-lvw-01070107090900090401010003-css tbody>tr:nth-child(even) {
    --bg-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .05)
  }
  
  .-lvw-01070107090900090401010003-css tbody>tr:nth-child(even) td {
    background-color: var(--bg-color);
  }
  
  .-lvw-01070107090900090401010003-css tbody>tr {
    border-bottom: 1px solid var(--gridcolor);
    color: black
  }
  
  .-lvw-01070107090900090401010003-css .splits {
    border-top: 1px solid var(--gridcolor)
  }
  
  .-lvw-01070107090900090401010003-css tbody>tr>td p {
    outline: none;
    width: 100%;
  }
  
  .-lvw-01070107090900090401010003-css tbody td {
    border-right: 1px solid var(--gridcolor)
  }
  
  .-lvw-01070107090900090401010003-css[nogrid] tbody * {
    border-color: transparent
  }
  
  .-lvw-01070107090900090401010003-css[nogrid] tbody>tr:nth-child(even)>td {
    border-color: var(--bg-color)
  }
  
  .-lvw-01070107090900090401010003-css[nowrap] p {
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden
  }
  
  .-lvw-01070107090900090401010003-css[checkboxes] td>div>div[checkbox] {
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    margin-right: 5px;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    background: white
  }
  
  .-lvw-01070107090900090401010003-css[checkboxes] td>div>div[checkbox="checked"]::after {
    content: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns=\'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\' x=\'0\' y=\'0\' viewbow=\'0 0 16 16\'%3E%3Cpath fill=\'black\' d=\'M4,9l0,-3l3,3l5,-5,l0,3l-5,5Z\' /%3E%3C/svg%3E");
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    position: absolute;
    left: -1.5px;
    top: -1px
  }
</style>



We can see the class being created dynamically here:
ListView.#lvwId = '-lvw-' + Array.from(Date.now().toString()).map(b => ('00' + b.toString(16)).slice(-2)).join('');
            ListView.#lvwCss = ListView.#lvwId + '-css';

It is dependent on date so I think what has happened is that the CSS being invoked is not in step with the dynamic code. They have to be created at the same time.

Does this really stick? Because running the snippet in my pc shows that the thead still scrolls with the other elements. Oh, sorry about this. My bad. I was dragging the wrong scroll bars. It do sticks.

I will look thoroughly my code because after confirming that all the digits in the root class name and in the ID in the style elements are the same mine still don't work. I don't know why there differences in the code I have posted because that id is generated just once when the style element is created. The #lvwId is a static field of the ListView class that store the id the given to the style element. #lvwCss is also a static field of the class that stores copy of #lvwId concatenated with the string '-css'. Therefore, that ID is not generated again when #lvwId no longer has a null value.

The d is irrelevant to your problem, it’s the classes not matching that is the problem

I was not expecting that result.  The descendant CSS rules have one common root class and the name the root class is expected to be consistent. The static function #initId() was there to ensure this. I don't know why the inconsistency in excerpts I posted.

To single out it is the inconsistency causing the problem, I skipped the dynamic creation of the ids in #initID(). Instead of this: ListView.#lvwId = '-lvw-' + Array.from(Date.now().toString()).map(b => ('00' + b.toString(16)).slice(-2)).join('');, I used this: ListView.#lvwId = '__ek-lvw-2024-';. But it didn't solve the problem.

I want to append the overall HTML structure so that the placement of the ek-listview is seen but I am exceeding the maximum limit...

This only works when the mark-up is hard coded and not when it is dynamically generated like in my case. When adding the component there is nothing more you can do beyond this: <ek-listview></ek-listview>. Although adding child elements is possible, it will break the purpose of the component.

First of all, guys, thank you for your time. In the widget or component or whatever it may be appropriately called, my main objective is to have a resizable header that sticks at the top. Whatever I did I just can’t make it happen. I tried to hardcode the enclosing div’s width and height but it still didn’t solve the problem.
I want this component to be as reusable as possible (at least, for me) without having to do other stuff aside from adding it to a web page. I mean, no more linking to external css and js files.
So, my solution, although I think not a permanent one but at least it serves the purpose, is to have two tables. The first will serve as the header and the other is the body.
Both tables are inside a div for the scrollbars.
The basic css goes like this:
table{border-collapse:collapse;z-index:0;left:0px;top:0px;background:white;table-layout:fixed}
table:first-of-type{position:sticky;top:0px;z-index:2}
table:last-child{position:absolute}

The dynamic creation of css is necessary to create an ID as unique as possible  for the style element. The purpose is to avoid collition with other elements’ IDs. The generated ID concatenated with the string '-css' will serve as the root class of the component to make all css rules scoped (I am not sure if it is the right term). This ID also ensures that only style is created for all instances of the component.
To ascertain the creation of the unique ID, this method is called
    static #initId() {
        if (ListView.#lvwId == null) {
            ListView.#lvwId = '-lvw-' + Array.from(Date.now().toString()).map(b => ('00' + b.toString(16)).slice(-2)).join('');
            ListView.#lvwCss = ListView.#lvwId + '-css';
        }
    }

And in the connectedCallback() function...
    connectedCallback() {
        ListView.#initId();
        let style = document.getElementById(ListView.#lvwId);
        if (style == null) {
            ListView.#style = style = document.createElement('style');
            style.type = 'text/css';
            style.id = ListView.#lvwId;
            const fn = (...b) => {
                if (b.length == 1) {
                    let c = b[0];
                    let d = '.' + ListView.#lvwCss;
                    if (c[0] == '-')
                        c = c.substr(1);
                    else
                        d += ' ';
                    d += c;
                    ListView.#style.appendChild(document.createTextNode(d));
                }
                else {
                    let c = '';
                    for (let d of b[0]) {
                        if (c != '') c += ',';
                        c += '.' + ListView.#lvwCss + ' ' + d;
                    }
                    ListView.#style.appendChild(document.createTextNode(c + ' ' + b[1]));
                }
            };
            fn('*{user-select:none;box-sizing:border-box;position:relative;padding:0px;margin:0px;background-color:transparent;color:inherit}');
            fn('{--gridcolor:lightgray;--xmargins:5px;--itembackcolor:white;--itemforecolor:black;--headerbackcolor:gray;--headerforecolor:black;--headerhoverback:forestgreen;--headerhoverfore:black;--headerpadding:4px;--itempadding:4px;}');
            fn('table{border-collapse:collapse;z-index:0;left:0px;top:0px;background:white;table-layout:fixed}');
            fn('table:first-of-type{position:sticky;top:0px;z-index:2}');
            fn('table:last-child{position:absolute}');
            fn('>div{width:100%;height:32px;overflow:hidden;position:sticky;left:0px;top:0px;background:gray}');
            fn(['th', 'td'], '{text-align:left;vertical-align:top;}');
            fn('th{background-color:var(--headerbackcolor);color:var(--headerforecolor);border-right:1px solid var(--gridcolor);transition:background-color .5s}');
            fn('-:not([headeronly]) th{cursor:pointer;}');
            fn('-:not([headeronly]) th:hover{background-color:var(--headerhoverback);color:var(--headerhoverfore)}');
            fn(['th>div', 'td>div'], '{height:100%;display:flex;flex-direction:row;justify-content:flex-start;align-content:flex-start;align-items:flex-start}');
            fn('th>div{margin-left:var(--xmargins);padding: var(--headerpadding) var(--xmargins) var(--headerpadding) 0px;}');
            fn('th>div>p{width:100%}');
            fn('thead>tr:not(:first-child){border-top:1px solid var(--gridcolor)}');
            fn('td{background:var(--itembackcolor);color:var(--itemforecolor);}');
            fn('th::after{content:"";width:var(--xmargins);position:absolute;right:0px;top:0px;height:100%;cursor:ew-resize}');
            fn('th:not(:first-child)::before{content:"";width:var(--xmargins);position:absolute;left:0px;top:0px;height:100%;cursor:ew-resize}');
            fn('td>div{padding:var(--xmargins) var(--itempadding);width:100%;}');
            fn('td>div>p>img{float:left;margin-right:5px}');
            fn('td>input{height:100%;width:100%;outline:0px solid transparent;border:none;padding:1px;background:white;color:black;}');
            fn('td{color:black}');
            fn('tr[selected]{background:#018;color:white}');
            fn('tr[selected]>td:not([selected]){background:transparent;color:white}');
            fn('tr[selected]>td[selected]{background:rgba(255,255,255,.2);}');
            fn('tbody>tr:nth-child(even){--bg-color:rgba(0,0,0,.05)}');
            fn('tbody>tr:nth-child(even) td{background-color:var(--bg-color);}');
            fn('tbody>tr{border-bottom:1px solid var(--gridcolor);color:black}');
            fn('tbody>tr>td p{outline:none;width:100%;}');
            fn('tbody td{border-right:1px solid var(--gridcolor)}');
            fn('-[nogrid] tbody * {border-color:transparent}');
            fn('-[nogrid] tbody>tr:nth-child(even)>td{border-color:var(--bg-color)}');
            fn('-[nowrap] p{white-space:nowrap;text-overflow:ellipsis;overflow:hidden}');
            fn('-[checkboxes] td>div>div[checkbox]{float:left;border:1px solid gray;margin-right:5px;width:16px;height:16px;background:white}')
            fn("-[checkboxes] td>div>div[checkbox=\"checked\"]::after{content: url(\"data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' x='0' y='0' viewbow='0 0 16 16'%3E%3Cpath fill='black' d='M4,9l0,-3l3,3l5,-5,l0,3l-5,5Z' /%3E%3C/svg%3E\");width:16px;height:16px;position:absolute;left:-1.5px;top:-1px}");
            fn('-[rowheader] th:first-child{position:sticky;left:0px}');
            fn('-[rowheader] td:first-child{position:sticky;left:0px}');
            document.body.insertAdjacentElement('beforebegin', style);
        }
        this.tabIndex = $(this).index();
        this.classList.add(ListView.#lvwCss);
        this.setAttribute('style', 'background-color:white;outline:none;display:block;overflow:auto;width:100%;height:100%');

        this.#headTable = document.createElement('table');
        this.#headColGroup = document.createElement('colgroup');
        this.#headTable.appendChild(this.#headColGroup);
        this.#thead = document.createElement('thead');
        this.#header = document.createElement('tr');
        this.#thead.appendChild(this.#header);
        this.#headTable.appendChild(this.#thead);
        this.appendChild(this.#headTable);

        this.#bodyTable = document.createElement('table');
        this.#bodyColGroup = document.createElement('colgroup');
        this.#bodyTable.appendChild(this.#bodyColGroup);
        this.#tbody = document.createElement('tbody');
        this.#bodyTable.appendChild(this.#tbody);
        this.appendChild(this.#bodyTable);

        this.#handleEvents();
        this.#handleHeaderEvents();

        const observer = new ResizeObserver(() => {
            const r = this.#headTable.getBoundingClientRect();
            this.#bodyTable.style.top = `${r.height}px`;
            this.#bodyTable.style.width = `${r.width}px`;
        });
        observer.observe(this.#headTable);
    }

Note that there is a fn() method inside the connectedCallback() method which obvious is responsible in placing the css rules. It also ensures that all rules are prepended with the ListView.#lvwCss value.
Regarding the ResizeObserver inside the connectedCallback, it is necessary to make sure that the position of the second table is right at the bottom of the first table. The header table height could change, first: when nowrap attribute is not specified when adding the component in the web page and, second: where there are split columns.
The basic mark-up could look like this:
<div class="the_generated_class_name" style="outline:none;display:block;overflow:auto;width:100%;height:100%">
    <table>
        <colgroup>
            ...cols added dynamically
        </colgroup>
        <thead>
            ...trs and ths are added dynamically
        </thead>
    </table>
    <table>
        <colgroup>
            ...cols added dynamically
        </colgroup>
        <tbody>
            ...trs and tds are added dynamically
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>

The <colgroup>’s main purpose is the synchronized resizing of columns of both tables. The component is fully customizable through the css variables provided and of course its design can still be manipulated through the last css rules or inline styles.
Since adding headers and rows are done via script, here is a sample script.
const lvw = document.getElementById('lvw');
lvw.headers.add(
    {
        name: 'name',
        text: 'Name',
        width: 250,
        valign: 'middle'
    },
    {
        name: 'datehired',
        text: 'Date Hired',
        width: 100,
        editable: true,
        deletable: false,
        type: 'date',
        valign: 'middle'
    },
    {
        name: 'service',
        text: 'Service Length',
        width: 120,
        valign: 'middle'
    },
    {
        name: 'position',
        text: 'Position',
        width: 120,
        valign: 'middle'
    },
    {
        name: 'salary',
        text: 'Salary',
        width: 90,
        alignment: 'right',
        editable: true,
        pseudotype: 'ufloat',
        valign: 'middle'
    },
    {
        name: 'payments',
        text: 'Payments',
        width: 110,
        alignment: 'right',
        valign: 'middle'
    },
    {
        name: 'sss',
        text: 'SSS',
        width: 200,
        alignment: 'center',
        splits: [
            {
                name: 'sssnum',
                text: 'Number',
                width: 120,
                editable: true
            },
            {
                name: 'sssshare',
                text: 'Share',
                width: 80,
                alignment: 'right',
                pseudotype: 'ufloat',
                editable: true
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        name: 'philhealth',
        text: 'PhilHealth',
        width: 200,
        alignment: 'center',
        splits: [
            {
                name: 'philhealthnum',
                text: 'Number',
                width: 120,
                editable: true
            },
            {
                name: 'philhealthshare',
                text: 'Share',
                width: 80,
                alignment: 'right',
                pseudotype: 'ufloat',
                editable: true
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        name: 'pagibig',
        text: 'Pag-Ibig',
        width: 200,
        alignment: 'center',
        splits: [
            {
                name: 'pagibignum',
                text: 'Number',
                width: 120,
                editable: true
            },
            {
                name: 'pagibigshare',
                text: 'Share',
                width: 80,
                alignment: 'right',
                pseudotype: 'ufloat',
                editable: true
            }
        ]
    }
);

After that call, the mark-up would look like this:
<div style="background-color:white;outline:none;display:block;overflow:auto;width:100%;height:100%">
    <table style="width: 1390px;">
        <colgroup>
            <col th-id="name" style="width: 250px;">
            <col th-id="datehired" style="width: 100px;">
            <col th-id="service" style="width: 120px;">
            <col th-id="position" style="width: 120px;">
            <col th-id="salary" style="width: 90px;">
            <col th-id="payments" style="width: 110px;">
            <col th-id="sssnum" style="width: 120px;">
            <col th-id="sssshare" style="width: 80px;">
            <col th-id="philhealthnum" style="width: 120px;">
            <col th-id="philhealthshare" style="width: 80px;">
            <col th-id="pagibignum" style="width: 120px;">
            <col th-id="pagibigshare" style="width: 80px;">
        </colgroup>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th id="name" rowspan="2" style="width: 250px; vertical-align: middle;"><div><p style="text-align: left;">Name</p></div></th>
                <th id="datehired" rowspan="2" style="width: 100px; vertical-align: middle;"><div><p style="text-align: left;">Date Hired</p></div></th>
                <th id="service" rowspan="2" style="width: 120px; vertical-align: middle;"><div><p style="text-align: left;">Service Length</p></div></th>
                <th id="position" rowspan="2" style="width: 120px; vertical-align: middle;"><div><p style="text-align: left;">Position</p></div></th>
                <th id="salary" rowspan="2" style="width: 90px; vertical-align: middle;"><div><p style="text-align: right;">Salary</p></div></th>
                <th id="payments" rowspan="2" style="width: 110px; vertical-align: middle;"><div><p style="text-align: right;">Payments</p></div></th>
                <th id="sss" rowspan="1" colspan="2" style="width: 200px;"><div><p style="text-align: center;">SSS</p></div></th>
                <th id="philhealth" rowspan="1" colspan="2" style="width: 200px;"><div><p style="text-align: center;">PhilHealth</p></div></th>
                <th id="pagibig" rowspan="1" colspan="2" style="width: 200px;"><div><p style="text-align: center;">Pag-Ibig</p></div></th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th id="sssnum" headers="sss" style="width: 120px;"><div><p style="text-align: left;">Number</p></div></th>
                <th id="sssshare" headers="sss" style="width: 80px;"><div><p style="text-align: right;">Share</p></div></th>
                <th id="philhealthnum" headers="philhealth" style="width: 120px;"><div><p style="text-align: left;">Number</p></div></th>
                <th id="philhealthshare" headers="philhealth" style="width: 80px;"><div><p style="text-align: right;">Share</p></div></th>
                <th id="pagibignum" headers="pagibig" style="width: 120px;"><div><p style="text-align: left;">Number</p></div></th>
                <th id="pagibigshare" headers="pagibig" style="width: 80px;"><div><p style="text-align: right;">Share</p></div></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
    <table style="top: 53.7812px; width: 1390.5px;">
        <colgroup>
            <col td-id="name" style="width: 250px;">
            <col td-id="datehired" style="width: 100px;">
            <col td-id="service" style="width: 120px;">
            <col td-id="position" style="width: 120px;">
            <col td-id="salary" style="width: 90px;">
            <col td-id="payments" style="width: 110px;">
            <col td-id="sssnum" style="width: 120px;">
            <col td-id="sssshare" style="width: 80px;">
            <col td-id="philhealthnum" style="width: 120px;">
            <col td-id="philhealthshare" style="width: 80px;">
            <col td-id="pagibignum" style="width: 120px;">
            <col td-id="pagibigshare" style="width: 80px;">
        </colgroup>
        <tbody>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>

And adding items goes like this:
    $.get('/datasource/', { data: cookies.sessionid,q:'e' }, data =>
    {
        for (let a of data.data) {
            const row = lvw.rows.add(a);
            row.salary = parseFloat(a.salary.replace(/,/g, ''));
            row.datehired = new Date(row.datehired);
        }
    });

Again, thank you.

While editing the answer, I noticed that even the IDs given to the table headers may collide with the IDs of other elements. To solve this I will have to prepend those IDs with the value of ListView.#lvwId.
